# How to overcome dictionary size limitation? Python3 on windows7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7

I have a script in python 3.6 what parses a .csv file on windows 7. The initial file is a kind of biological analyzer output. I need to make it more human-readable, so I add the comments based on the data in the initial file. I use dictionaries to keep such comments. The script also has a GUI made with Tkinter library.

Everything worked well before I added some extra keys to the dict_2. Now the script cannot be run via double click anymore. However, it still works if I run the script by Thonny.

Are there any ways to overcome this dictionary size limitation?

Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct 3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

def callback():
    if askyesno('Verify', 'Close?'):
        master.destroy()
    else:
        showinfo('No', 'Continue')

def make_report():
    csv_filename =  askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Chose file",filetypes = (("Report","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    txt_filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "resulting file*.txt",filetypes = (("txt","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))

    if (str(csv_filename)!= "" ) and str(txt_filename)!= "":


        with open (str(csv_filename), 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as tsvin:
            tsvin = csv.reader (tsvin, delimiter=';')
            with open (str(txt_filename) , 'w') as fileOut:
                exlc_list = []
                dict_1 = {'x1':'x1a', ...., 'x67':'x67a'}
                dict_2 = {'y1':'x1a', ...., 'y216':'y216a'}
                .....
```

Comment: I don't think there is a fixed dictionary limitation size.

Comment: how big is too big?

Comment: I checked it. If I add a new element or just space to dict_2, it causes the problem. I still can add elements to dict_1 without any negative consequences.

Comment: I have 216 elements in my "big" dictionary and apperently I cannot add more.